# Laravel Mix+vite не указывается версия css и js в blade шаблоне

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-mix

В html не указывается версия css и js.

Содержимое vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        outDir: 'public/build',
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Содержимое webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const VitePlugin = require('laravel-mix-vite');
mix.extend('vite', new VitePlugin());
mix
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/assets')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/assets', [])
    .vite();
if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

Вывожу в blade шаблоне так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/assets/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('build/assets/app.js') }}"></script>
```

ещё пробывал mix метод в шаблоне, тоже самое.

Файл build\manifest.json создается, файлы в нем указаны с версиями.

Comment: Для Laravel MIX можно использовать хелпер [mix()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-mix) он будет возвращать URL к Вашему скомпилированному файлу, включая версионный хеш.

Comment: @Simon, я воспользовался mix-ом, у меня ссылка теперь такая <link rel="stylesheet" href="//127.0.0.1:5173/build/assets/app.css">, хотя php artisan serve крутится на http://127.0.0.1:8000/
И как видно, версии опять не прицепились.

Я воспользовался контейнерами написанными aschmelyun/docker-compose-laravel.
npm команды я запускаю через docker-compose run --rm npm